# Spring MVC 3.1 Serving Static Resources

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I'm trying to solve what seems to be a common problem of trying to serve static resources such as images, style sheets and scripts from my Java Web App. I've tried a lot of the solutions offered in other threads but have gotten nowhere, all I get is 404 errors on the resource calls.

The only other thing I can think of is that I'm running on Tomcat 7, but if I try putting 6 on I get a "The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification." error, so that looks like a no go. Does anyone have any ideas where I might be going wrong?

My project is structured as so:

```
WebContent

    META-INF

    Resources

        CSS

        Images

            close.jpg

        Scripts 

    WEB-INF

        Lib

        Views

            index.jsp
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="uk.ac.ncl.controllers" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index()
{
    return "index";
}
```

My View

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Index - ViralPatel.net</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page with image</h1>
        <!-- use c:url to get the correct absolute path -->
        <img src="<c:url value="/resources/images/close.png" />" />
        <img src="http://localhost:8080${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/close.png" />
    <a href="map">View Map</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be a case-sensitivity issue? Your html says `/resources/image`s but your tree looks like `/Resources/Images`

Comment: I'm afraid not, I've changed everything to lowercase and it still doesn't work